# HIghcharts - chart width not the size of the parent container

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to figure out why I have [that chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSpZs.png)  wider than the container. I noticed that if I remove the width completely [for the first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2qd9.png) and then set width: 100% in the next. However, I am not able to force this styles and I think this is not the right way to go.

Here are the settings of my chart. Apart from that, I do not use any other css.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
            renderTo: 'container10',
            type: 'line',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            spacingRight: 5,
            height: 370,
            width: 770
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Database volume'
          },
          colors:['#229369', '#00526F'],
          xAxis: { 
            categories: catValues
          },
          yAxis: [{
            title: {
              text: 'Table size in MB'
            },
            labels: {
              style: {
                  color: '#229369'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            title: {
              text: 'Index size in MB'
            },
            labels: {
              style: {
                  color: '#00526F'
              }
            },
            opposite: true
          }],
          tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: ' MB'
          },
          plotOptions: {
            line: {
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
              },
              enableMouseTracking: true
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'Table',
            data: series1,
          }, {
            name: 'Index',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: series2
          }]
      });
```

Comment: It looks to me as though you've set a `width` in your chart settings that is wider than your container. What behavior are you expecting in that case?

Comment: Well, in that case, yes it is a bit too big. However, when I lowered the value I got the opposite problem - chart being too small for the container.
I managed to fix it by calling the setSize() method.

Comment: It seems I made a mistake. This works only under Chrome. Firefox shows the chart smaller and Safari is making it a bit larger. Any ideas why?
Thanks!

Comment: If you do not set the width/height of the chart in options, it should inherit those attributes from the container.

Comment: @Petya so what you're saying is, the chart ends up the size that you tell the chart to you want it to be. So either 1) set the chart's size to what you actually want it to be, or 2) as morgan said, don't set a size in the chart options at all.

Comment: Hi! Thank you both for the comments. 
I removed the width&height, and now they are replaced by the default values 600x400px, which results in the same problem. See the picture (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Eh3urpxwp1cXRQeFBaLWdDcXc). The parent container is the right size, but the chart is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct way of fixing that, but seems to work. I set the width of the container of the chart directive.

```
.chart-wrapper {
  width: 99%;
}
```

Then in the directive code onDataLoaded or windowResized I call this:

```
function resize() {
  height = chart.height;
  width = $(".chart-wrapper").width();
  chart.setSize(width, height, doAnimation = false);
}
```